# Set Alarm on multiple days using local notification in ios 10 +Objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios10, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

I use UNUserNotificationCenter for local notification. I want to fire a local notification on multiple days from present date and if user select repeat then every week on same day and same time notification fire which days are selected by user. So i use the below code.

```
 NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear|NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:now];//get the required calendar units

if (components.weekday>4)
{
    components.weekOfYear+=1;//if already passed monday, make it next monday
}
components.weekday = 4;//Wednesday
components.hour = 12;
NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
UNUserNotificationCenter *centerMonday;

UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
objNotificationContent.title = @"change time";
objNotificationContent.body = @"This is local notification message! Every Wednesday";
objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];

/// 4. update application icon badge number
objNotificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1);


 NSDateComponents *triggerDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond fromDate:fireDate];
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:triggerDate repeats:YES];
UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"swami12"
                                                                      content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
/// 3. schedule localNotification
centerMonday = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
centerMonday.delegate= self;
[centerMonday addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Local Notification succeeded");
     }
     else
     {

         NSLog(@"Local Notification failed");
     }
 }];
```

So here i set repeat yes but notification comes only once on selected day not repeat every week. Help, I stuck here from last three days.Thanks

Comment: Try removing `NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear ` from your trigger; otherwise it is set to repeat each year in that month on that particular day. You'll want to add `NSCalendarUnitWeekday` to specify the day of the week to schedule the repeating weekly notification along with the time info (hour, minute, seconds) you have already.